# Bread machine bread dough

Tags: bread

I wanted to bake bread in the oven. I used my bread machine to do the dough part it rise twice in the machine.
I couldn't finish it so I put in fridge over night it rise for a third time. I took it out to get to room temperature. It went down in size. It is in bread pan ready to be bake do I let it rise again for Fourth rise .I didn't knead it I took it out put on counter. Would it rise again? Is it lost? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's worth a try letting your bread rise again as you've come this far, however the chances of it coming out well aren't great. Your bread will rise as long as there is enough sugar for the yeast to consume in the dough, if the food supply is exhausted the yeast will die and your bread will collapse, and it's a strong possibility that's happened to you.

However, it could be that you knocked the air out and the yeast is still going, so let it warm up to room temperature and see. If it rises then bake it, if it doesn't get rid of it as it'll come out dense and gummy.